# Return data where any part of StartDate and EndDate fall within filter date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of product records with a StartDate and EndDate. I also have a StartDate and EndDate filter settings passed in as params.

**The goal:**
Return any products where any part of the Product Date Range falls in between or equal to the filter settings Date Range.

**Here is my attempt but it is not working:**

```
((@FilterStartDate <= prod.StartDate AND @FilterStartDate <= prod.EndDate)
OR
(@FilterEndDate >= prod.StartDate AND @FilterEndDate <= prod.EndDate))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want this simplified version to just check if the start or end falls in the range...

```
where
    (prod.StartDate >= @FilterStartDate and prod.StartDate <= @FilterEndDate)
    or 
    (prod.EndDate  >= @FilterStartDate and prod.EndDate <= @FilterEndDate)
```

Comment: One problem though. Lets say the filter StartDate is 1/1/2015 and filter EndDate is 12/31/2015. A product with StartDate: 1/1/2016 and EndDate 6/31/2016 will still show. The start in range will validate as true when I wouldn't want this product record to show.

Comment: No it won't @BlakeRivell. Look at the simplified version. The `prod.StartDate <= @FilterEndDate` thus wouldn't show. It's the boolean AND with parentheses that forces this.

Comment: I see the simplified version is fine. The other version was not working.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Glad the simplified one worked then brother

Comment: The "simplified" version is still overly complicated, the logic simplifies even further.

Comment: @DavidG just because it can be simplified further doesn't mean it is overly complicated. They are not synonymous.

Comment: Well the difference between `condition1 AND coindition2` and `(coindition1 AND coindition2) OR (coindition3 AND coindition4)` seems pretty overly complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check that the filter start date is before the product end date and the filter end date is after the project start date, for example:

```
@FilterStartDate <= prod.EndDate 
AND @FilterEndDate >= prod.StartDate
```

Comment: this will not work. Lets say the filter dates are 1/1/2015 through 12/31/2015. The product dates are 1/1/2016 through 12/31/2016. Your expression will pass as true when it should not.

Comment: Yes it will work because of the second part of the clause `@FilterEndDate >= prod.StartDate`. Note that it is combined with the first with an `AND`.

Comment: No worries, date logic can be confusing sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates column is actually datetime, you can try

WHERE prod.StartDate >= 'yourStartDate' AND prod.EndDate < 'yourEndDate'

or, if it's not datetime and you prefer casting:

WHERE CAST(dates as date) BETWEEN 'yourStartDate' and 'yourEndDate'.